# Why can't I print a Unicode character in Python from a .DLL file?

Tags: python, c, dll, unicode

I made a .DLL project in Visual Studio (with C, not C++), and I have a function as follows:

```
//lib.c
void print_star() {
    printf("\u2606"); //should print: ☆
}
//lib.h
#pragma once

#ifdef LIB_EXPORTS
#define LIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

LIB void print_star();
```

I then compiled it into a .DLL file with Build>Build Solution, and then imported the .DLL file into a python project in this way:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\\path\\to\\lib.dll")

lib.print_star()
```

However, when I execute the Python code, it does not print a star, but instead just `?`.
I tried putting the actual character in the source code, but I simply got this error when building:

```
warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2606' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I make it print the star?

Comment: Windows is extremely unfriendly when it comes to Unicode support. The simplest, easiest, most painless way to solve this problem is to switch OS. Linux works out of the box.

Comment: Failing that, try compiling with /utf-8 compiler switch (there should be a way to set it from the VS GUI but I have no idea where).

Comment: Do you see the correct character get printed if you call ‘print_star()’ from a native C program?  What about if you try to print the Unicode character directly in Python, without using the DLL?

Comment: @charon00 yes, both work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I have found a method that works for me.

First, I compiled the code with UTF-8 instead of UTF-16. I went to: Project > [projectname] Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command line, and adding '/utf-8' to the "Additional Options" textbox. (Thanks to @n. m. for that)

Second, I changed the code in the C File to this:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void print_star() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"%s", (wchar_t*) L"☆"); //using "\u2606" instead of the star also works
}
```

Thankfully, I did not have to change any of the code in the python file.